# Any way to rotate mesh segments in a curve without converting it to a mesh? (hair by curves/beziers method)

Tags: bezier-curves, hair

I have a hair I'm building based on [this tutorial](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=BqWYgrXw7Jk). He mentions you can "scale" (shrink/fatten) a curve segment's mesh with Alt+S. Is there a similar way to rotate the mesh? I would like to make my hair strands bend around the head like one of the green curves, and I don't have a good enough grasp of bezier circles to use that (plus, I'm making way too many of them).

Secondary question, is there a way to re-UV map these curves? I understand it's automatically done now and there's no "Curves tab -> Texture Space -> use UV mapping" anymore, but the auto-map makes an abrupt transition right on the front of each strand (texture I want to use is a white to blue linear gradient) and I'd like to have it not do that.

[image]

Comment: Ctrl + T could be what you need

Comment: @Emir At a quick trial, that was just what I needed! Perfect! Hopefully that'll save me some bezier circles.